# How to kill Uldred on Dragon Age: Origins?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I am in the mage tower now with Shale, Morrigan and Zevran and I am facing Uldred.

I am siding with the templars, because Morrigan said so, and I am having a really hard time beating Uldred.

I have been trying over 10 tries already, and it is starting to annoy me.

I do not have any healing spells and have some health potions left. I am a warrior human. Together with Shale, that makes two tanks.

Now I've read somewhere that you need to use that spell you get from the other mage to stop the abominations from appearing, or something. Have not tried that, but...

What would be the best course of action to beat this enemy?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note as it's propably already too late: I think it's always good to have a dedicated healer mage in the party, makes a lot of fights easier. Anyways, for this particular fight i can't help you since it was quite a while ago and i can't remember it, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I killed Wynn :).. Perhaps I should get some healing spells for Morrigan instead..

Comment: To add to what others have said, you can also set the difficulty down just for the fight and put it back up after. You don't "need" a dedicated healer, but if you don't have one you should have potions instead (use crafting recipes to make them)

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that, but the difficulty is locked in, so I could not change it. Missing Wynn I did not know to use the litany...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick to the fight is to use the litany every time he's going to convert a mage into an abomination.

I did that and the fight went fine - I don't remember it being particularly difficult.

If I remember correctly, Wynne shouts out each time you need to use the litany, so if you've killed her, this could be a bit trickier, but I think both Uldred and the mage glow white when he's about to convert them

Comment: Uldred shouts out something as well if Wynne isn't in your party. I can't remember what he says, but I played through a solo run of the game and didn't have any trouble using the Litany whenever needed on my own.

Comment: I did it. With the litany its pretty easy actually. I got it in 1 try and 3 health potions. It really does make the difference.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a mage with Cone of Cold abuse it. That can freeze any enemy (even the Arch demon) Should at least give you time to beat on him for a few free seconds. Also As mentioned in Durathor's answer:

> The trick to the fight is to use the litany every time he's going to convert a mage into an abomination.

Also if you have anyone that can use poisons, most of them do a lot of damage and don't cost you any Stamina or Magic to use. So use them.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have healing spells you will have to count on your health poultices, so you should set the tactics of every party members in this way: Self > Health > less than 50% > Use healing items less powerful.
For the spell you have to use it when the mage are transforming into abomination, you should notice whirlpools of light around them.
I suggest to make Morrigan spiritual healer as soon as possible. It's a very handy class.
If you still keep dying try to set the difficulty to casual. It should be a piece of cake.

Answer (score -1):

When you get out of the fade you should get an item; some kind of paper if I remember correctly. You can use it in the menu were you open your inventory. It might be in advanced options. I'm not sure if you have to side with the mages to get this, or even enter the fade, but it does quite a bit of damage if you keep using it. You will lose it after the battle though.